# Is it true that in OAuth 2.0 implicit grant flow, "JS" is present anyhow?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, implicit, sql-grant

Lets say that we have an android app and we're using `OAuth 2.0`  implicit grant flow for authorization.

**The question is that** do we have JS,HTML in the middle for authorization and handling of access token or can we get authorized just by our android app?

Answer (score 1):

Except client credentials method, you need to visit website to put your id/pw. If you are using android app, implicit method would be good.